# Долго ищет почту с Full Text в MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Всем привет! MSSQL, 100К записей. Возникла проблема поиска электронной почты. если указывать почту где чаще встречается точка то поиск выполняется долго (2-3 секунды). Для сравнения если указать ooostm@yandex.ru то найдет не более секунды. Что можно сделать чтобы быстро находить похожие почты?

Comment: Возможно `.` воспринимается как любое кол-во любых символов, если строка как `regexp` воспринимается. Если вам нужно именно такое поведение - то ничего сделать нельзя. Если же вам надо именно символ точки, а не любое кол-во любых символов, то точку надо экранировать. Это везде по разному делается. Попробуйте, для начала, перед точкой обратный слэш поставить. Типа вот так: `\.`

Comment: попробуйте использовать OPTIMIZE FOR!

Answer (score 1):

Можешь создать новый FullText Index, по которому ищет Contains, вот [Статья](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/full-text-index-in-sql-server/) как это сделать